# AngularJS reloading page after remove element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to remove an element inside `ngRepeat`. It's removing well, but after the element is removed, the page is reloaded. How can I prevent this reload action?

Heres the code:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <p>{{task.title}}</p>
    <button ng-click="remove($index)">Click me</button>
</li>
```

js scope:

```
$scope.remove = function($index){
    $scope.tasks.splice($index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why would button click reload the page? Are you sure you have button, not link with some href, and not form that gets submitted?

Comment: Sounds like it's the only button inside of a form and it's assuming submit. Confirm it by preventing default action off the event or moving the button outside of your closing form tag.

Comment: @dfsq yes, its a `button`. @Antiga I just changed it to an `anchor` and it worked! Thanks. By the way, its not a `form`

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos See my answer for more info and why it's behaving that way.

Answer (score 4):

As per the W3C spec, the type is undefined and it's assuming a submit. Adding `type='button'` should resolve the issue for you.

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <p>{{task.title}}</p>
    <button type="button" ng-click="remove($index)">Click me</button>
</li>
```

Relevant [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.html) if you're curious.

Comment: You are right. I changed it to `input[type=button]` but it's still reloading. So I changed it to `<a />` and worked.

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos Happy to hear you figured it out. Please consider marking answers that solve your problem as the *Answer*. It's helpful for question visibility.

Answer (score 1):

`<button>` was acting like a `submit` (thanks to @Antiga), I tried to change it to `input[type=button]` but still didn't work.

I just made this change:

```
<button ng-click="remove($index)">Click me</button>
```

to:

```
<a ng-click="remove($index)">Click me</a>
```

And it worked well.